# Issue with Toggled Street View Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to customize a toggled Street view Map I am struggling with some issues on customizing map controls and functions.As you can see from this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/W6hFT/1/) I can toggle the maps but I am confused on using the Street View Maps properties!

Can you please let me know how I can do this? Foe example I would like to remove the White Direction arrows on the street view or that transparent white box for zooming and only display the street, how I can set properties outside of the map options?

I try to customize

```
var panorama = map.getStreetView();
panorama.setPosition(fenway);
panorama.linksControl(true);
panorama.ControlPosition = BOTTOM_CENTER;
panorama = panControl(false);
panorama.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not listed in the current documentation, but there is a `setOptions`-method for a streetViewPanorama, use this method to set the properties:

```
  panorama = map.getStreetView();

  panorama.setOptions(
    { position:           fenway,
      linksControl:       false,
      addressControl:     false,
      panControl:         false,
      zoomControlOptions:{ position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
                           style:    google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL }
    });
```

Note: the white arrows are the `linksControl`, the transparent box AFAIK can't be removed.

Comment: Perfect Thanks Dr. I was lost there! also thanks for your hints

Comment: Just one final question , how I can remove the address box? Thanks

Comment: set the `addressControl`-property to false(see  my edited code)