# How to Remove/Update "Address Is Approximate" From addressControl

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Thanks to [Dr.Molle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459897/dr-molle) cooments on my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869880/issue-with-toggled-street-view-map), now,  I know that we can filter displaying the addressControl. But what if I want to ONLY remove or update a part of the box.For example I want to keep the address line but remove the "Address Is Approximate" message since I am sure that I am in 100% correct address.Can you lease help me to figure this one out too?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to modify the existing text.  Add your own div or custom control containing only the address.

**Update to address additional questions in comment:**

> Do I have to hard code the address in new custom div?

No.

> Is there a way to grab address from addresscontrol?

I wouldn't think so.  Where do you get the position of the panorama from?  If it is an address, use that.  If it is a position, you can get an approximate address by reverse geocoding the position (which is what I suspect Google is doing and why it says "address is approximate") Please post a complete example of your code (or at least enough of it to reproduce the behavior you are trying to change) if you want help with it.

> Can you please help me to find a sample/ example of adding custom div containing address 
>   on the top of map?

[See the documentation on Custom Controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls)

Comment: Thanks geocodezip, Do I have to hard code the address  in new custom div? or is there a way to grab address from addresscontrol ? Can you please help me to find a sample/ example of adding custom div containing address on the top of map? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you. The 'address control' on my embedded street view map was not appearing the same as it was in the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-embed) demo. In their demo the 'address control' had the address, a pin icon, and a 'View on Google Maps' link.
On my embedded map, the 'address control' only had the address and text below reading 'Address is Approximate'. At first I thought it was my lat/lng causing the issue but I tested my embed using the same values in the Google Docs demo and still had the issue.

What ended up fixing this issue for me was adding the `signed_in=true` parameter to my Google API script like so:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initGoogleMaps" async defer></script>
```

Hopefully this will fix the issue for you!